# Does the term micro-architecture have a meaning outside of microprocessors?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, asic

Wikipedia defines microarchitecture as follows:

> In computer engineering, microarchitecture, also called computer
> organization and sometimes abbreviated as µarch or uarch, is the way a
> given instruction set architecture (ISA) is implemented in a
> particular processor. A given ISA may be implemented with different
> microarchitectures; implementations may vary due to different
> goals of a given design or due to shifts in technology.

Now my question is, does this term have any meaning outside of microprocessors as a general term for digital circuits implemented in FPGA and ASICs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure does. In a more general sense, microarchitecture refers to the flow of data and control in a digital design, and the logical structure that implements that flow. So microarchitecture isn't specific to CPU design, it could apply to any digital system.

For example, a 1-dimensional FIR filter could be implemented as an array of multiply-accumulate blocks, or it could use a DSP-type arrangement where the same MAC block is repeatedly used for the core multiply-accumulate operation and fed coefficients from a register file and controlled by a sequencer. These microarchitecture options present different trade-offs in throughput vs. area that implement the same computational function.

Comment: Further, the transitions table for a simple state-machine processor might in some cases reasonably be called "microcode" if the state-machine processor is not intended as a general-purpose CPU, but is instead designed to trigger various actions within the enclosing microarchitecture.  For example, a filter block might have a state table that controls the sequence in which registers get loaded, multiplied, and added, but lack any form of pointer arithmetic beyond triggering a DMA cycle (advancing a pointer in the DMA unit) , or any form of branching beyond stopping on a DMA-complete signal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Back in the days when GPU ASICs were designed with fixed function units instead of fully programmable shaders with ISAs, the choice and arrangement of the (graphics geometry and pixel data) processing blocks was still called the GPU microarchitecture.